# Using the published date and a custom date field to create a view with fields from two content types?

Tags: views

I am trying to create a view that displays fields from two content types. Type A has a custom date field, and I want to display a field from Type B when the custom date field in Type A is on the same day as the published date of Type B. Only one Type B node gets created each day.